# Why doesn't my find and replace code work properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find and .replaceWith some text, for example:

> **absdef** replace with **111111**
>
> **abcdefgiop** replace with **22222222**

But when my text looks like

> abcdef, abcdefgi

.replaceWith work poorly for me and I get something like this:

> **111111**, 111111giop

I use this code:

```
$("*").contents().each(function() {
    if(this.nodeType == 3)
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace("absdef", "111111");
});
//
$("*").contents().each(function() {
    if(this.nodeType == 3)
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace("abcdefgiop", "22222222");
});
```

Comment: Show us the exact markup and exact code that you're having trouble with please.

Comment: Set the second replace first and it will do the job.

Comment: I can not know for sure which came first, that's the problem.

Comment: In your actual code, did you mean `this.nodeValue.replace("abcdef", "111111");` instead of `this.nodeValue.replace("absdef", "111111");`? If so, @VisioN's suggestion will work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the order and concat them.

```
$("*").contents().each(function() {
    if(this.nodeType == 3)
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace("abcdefgiop", "22222222")
                                       .replace("abcdef", "111111");
});
```